Preview state of azure pipeline yaml after supplying it with runtime parameters
Sometimes I wonder... What the hell is my pipeline looking like when I build it with some parameters. I have many customizations based on those and at times I'm lost when trying to deduce how it would look like.
Is it somehow possible to see "built" version of yaml? In Azure or with third-party tools?

To know how the parameters of a YAML pipeline are expanded during a build, we can download logs of the build; and in the downloaded logs.zip file, we can proceed to check the azure-pipelines-expanded.yaml file.
Original YAML pipeline definition

azure-pipelines-expanded.yaml

Besides, we are able to find the expanded value for the runtime parameter in the logs from the web UI and the initializeLog.txt file from the downloaded logs.zip package file.

In addition, if your runtime parameter has a default value, you can download full YAML via pipeline editor to preview the expanded YAML definition with default values before a build.


I wanted to mention another option for viewing the expanded YAML, which doesn't require running the pipeline first, which is to use the endpoint described in this Microsoft documentation:
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/preview?api-version=6.1-preview.1

Example using the browser fetch API (e.g., in devtools in the browser):
fetch("https://dev.azure.com/<myorg>/<myproject>/_apis/pipelines/<myPipelineId>/preview?api-version=6.1-preview.1", {
    "method": "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "stagesToSkip":[],
        "resources": {
            "repositories": {
                "self": {
                    "refName": "refs/heads/<mybranchname>"
                }
            }
        },
        "templateParameters": {},
        "variables":{}
    }),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }})
    .then(x => x.json())
    .then(console.log)

One additional way to do it, appears to be to simply go to the pipeline editor (i.e., "Edit" the pipeline in the ADO user interface), then in the upper right, use the dropdown and click "Download full YAML".

This is a nice way to preview without having to queue a pipeline run and waiting for it to finish to download the logs.
